# Openning a PDF to a new window using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to open a .pdf that is associated with a certain product. I am using PHP to display the product and its information. I then want to when a link is clicked have that PDF open in a new window.

I have these variables set up.

```
<?php
    require_once("connect.php");
    $thisone = $_GET['id'];

    $allMov = "SELECT * FROM tbl_handbags WHERE handbags_id=".$thisone;

    $movResults = mysql_query($allMov);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($movResults);
    $filename = $row['filename_pdf'];
    $prefix = "pdfs";
?>
```

And then this

```
<?php echo "<a target = '_blank'  href='$prefix/$filename' >View and Download Spec Sheet .PDF </a>";?>
```

What is happening is that a new window opens however its the PDFS "Parent Directory". Here I can click on the proper PDF and it does what I want it to do. I just need to cut out the parent directory page somehow.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Sounds like you're storing the "parent directory" into the `filename_pdf` column instead of the actual file name.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the poster showed no evidence of having done any research of their own

Comment: check $filename, i think it is empty, that is why you are landing in pdfs directory, also place a blank index.html in pdfs directory to save directory browsing.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more clear. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! The issue was that when i imported the Database the filename_pdf was erased or not saved so I had to add another column with the corresponding PDFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviuor you see is because the string

```
"$prefix/$filename"
```

-or similarly-

```
$prefix . '/' . $filename
```

is a path that instead of pointing to the PDF file points to its parent directory.

Your web server is configured to allow directory listing (one thing that I would avoid in production) so you see all the files and then can click the file and open it...

**In the code you posted there is nothing that obviously is wrong and make this happen.**

So I suggest to edit the second part of your code (that renders the page) and temporarily replace it with

```
<?php echo "prefix = " . $prefix . "\n<br />" . "filename = " . $filename;
```

Either `$prefix`, `$filename` or **both** are wrong, with the above code you dump their content and you'll be able to narrow your debugging.